# Mac OS X Lion Apache Server not Found

Tags: apache-http-server, macos

After upgrading to Lion 10.7.2 today, Apache virtual hosts are not working anymore. When I go to `http://XYZ.localhost`, it say "*server not found*".

I am using Apache on my Mac OS X Lion and until today, it was working fine. I can access `http://localhost` but I can't access `http://XYZ.localhost`

My `/etc/hosts` file is like below;

```
127.0.0.1   XYZ.localhost
```

My `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file is like below;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName XYZ.localhost
    DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/XYZ
    <Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/XYZ>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I think I once had this problem too, after another OS X update, but I can't remember how I solved it.

Is it a user permission issue? Or is there something wrong with Apache or any other setting?

**EDIT:** It seems like my `/etc/hosts` file is not working correctly. Even if I add something like `127.0.0.1 apple.com` it still goes to the real apple.com. Maybe this might help to solve the problem.

Comment: Just a quick suggestion, try putting in Options FollowSymLinks within the <Directory> section.

Comment: Thanks ioi, I added Options FollowSymLinks but still no change. It was working before the Lion 10.7.2 update. There might be something wrong with permissions or hosts or something. This is so nonsense.

Comment: http://www.justincarmony.com/blog/2011/07/27/mac-os-x-lion-etc-hosts-bugs-and-dns-resolution/

Comment: No problem. I've put an answer that might help, although as you've said your /etc/hosts is not working -- so maybe that's it.

Comment: @quanta You are great, thank you so much. That solved my problem. Apple did change something with DNS and broke everything. If you answer my question, I would love to accept that as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it was working and now it's not working again. I think this question needs to be asked as a `hosts` file bug in Lion.

Answer (score 0):

You need this in your conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

So it should look like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName XYZ.local
DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/XYZ
<Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/XYZ>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You may also need to edit your main httpd.conf to include the httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: I have it in /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf already. I just updated the question about `hosts` file. Maybe that might help.

Comment: The hosts file seems like the culprit.